# How to output the value (json) from the string into the name of the column and its value?

Tags: postgresql

I have such fields

```
id   name  min_price  price_and_dealer

001  milk      5        [{"price": 5.00, "dealer": "Metro"}, {"price": 10.00, "dealer": "Dealer"}]
002  juice    15        [{"price": 25.00, "dealer": "Nike"}, {"price": 20.00, "dealer": "Shop"}, {"price": 15.00, "dealer": "Nike"}]
```

and I want to get this

```
id   name   min_price Metro Dealer Nike  Shop

001  milk      5        5     10   null  null
002  juice    15      null   null   15    20
```

How can I do that? I will be grateful for any help

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, 12.2

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eaQG8H4yqY9hnQBZjzJgz/37 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON/Path expression to get that, e.g.

```
jsonb_path_query_first(price_and_dealer, '$[*] ? (@.dealer == "Metro").price')
```

You need to write one expression for each output column you need.

This assumes that `price_and_dealer` is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not, you need to cast it `price_and_dealer::jsonb`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1214b059aa6f6659e6bd21d1f8ac9f15)

Comment: I have many clients, each will have a different set of dealers, different dealers names and different quantities. I want to create column titles and fill them dynamically

Comment: @Sanya: that is not possible. A fundamental restriction of the SQL language is that the number, names and types of all result column must be known to the database when it parses the query. You can't have a query that returns a different number of columns each time you run it.